# Interpreting Scaled Continuous Variables' and Unscaled Dummy Variables' Regression Co-efficient

Tags: regression, classification, categorical-data, data-transformation

I have regression coefficients, Logistic Regression to be precise, of 7 continuous and 2 binary (1 or 0) flag variables. The continuous variables are scaled using just the standard deviation of the individual variables to interpret them as the change in the probability of the response variable with 1 std. dev. change from their respective mean. And the coefficient magnitude of these continuous variables will tell which one will have more effect on the response than the other.

Now, I'm struggling to bring the unscaled binary flag variables into the mix. How should I be interpreting their coefficients? and How do their coefficients compare with the coefficients of the scaled continuous variables?

For instance, let's say that the coefficient of one of the binary flag variables (A) is 1.34 and the coefficient of one of the continuous variables (B) is 0.56. Is it right to interpret that as A is has a bigger impact on the response than B?

I'll very much appreciate your take on this. I have come across plenty of questions on scaling and unscaling the dummy variables but nothing on their interpretability.

Comment: How would you interpret the binary predictors if the model only had those?

Comment: probability of a response if the binary preditor was 1. The question is how to interpret them together with the continuous variables. How to rank the effectiveness of these variables based on their coefficients

Comment: Maybe it's just a matter of looking at them separately but if there was a way of interpreting them together, I would like to know.

Comment: How do you normally interpret a dummy variable?

Comment: I would interpret that as to whether the presence of the dummy variable is significant in determining the outcome and the amount of effect the dummy variable will have on the probability of getting a response based on its coefficient. I would like to clarify though, that the dummy variable I'm referring to in my question is the binary flag variable and not the actual dummy variable created out of a categorical variable. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I have edited the question - hoping it is a bit more clear!